# CAS single logout callback hits 403(forbidden)

Tags: java, spring, cas

I rephrased question and deleted old one. Hopefully I will get answers now.

CAS server attempt to send a callback request on SLO to protected app:

```
<Error Sending message to url endpoint [http://localhost:8080/j_spring_cas_security_check]. Error is [Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/j_spring_cas_security_check]>
```

On debug the `org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter` never gets hit.

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                addFilter(casFilter()).
                addFilterBefore(requestSingleLogoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class).
                addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8080/j_spring_cas_security_logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home2").hasAuthority("USER").and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(casEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


Filter casFilter() {
    CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
    casAuthenticationFilter.setServiceProperties(getServiceProperties());
    casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(getProviderManager());
    return casAuthenticationFilter;

}

LogoutFilter requestSingleLogoutFilter() {
    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter("http://localhost:8089/cas/logout",
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());
    logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/j_spring_cas_security_logout");
    return logoutFilter;
}


SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
    SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    return singleSignOutFilter;
}

 @Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addListener(new   org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener());
}
```

I have everything apart from the logout. Currently it invalidates the session thanks to LogoutFilter, destroys the ticket(on redirect to CAS) BUT if the SLO request would be sent from other protected application, obviously it will have no impact on this application(as sessionid will still be here).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same situation (403 status code) with CAS SLO, in my spring security log I found:

```
Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/j_spring_cas_security_check
```

so I disabled csrf filter in my security config:

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

This might not be a good practice, just a quick solution that works for me now. Also I am not shure if I can get the right csrf token if SLO is initiated in other protected application.

Comment: We figured it out ourself in the nightmare of Spring filter chain logs. Was too lazy to add the answer. Thx for that, hope it will save smbdy time.

Comment: Can you share if you have found any better solution than just disabling csrf?

Comment: We just stick to the solution you provided, you might be able to refine the disabling of csrf by applying it just to the logout end point address (default is smth like: /j_spring_cas_security_logout) http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfFilter.html setRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher method which accepts ant matcher. Or override it completely to set up extra criterias(hidden and not exposed to potential attackers in client side code) the request should meet in order to be NOT processed by the filter.

Comment: In the end even if the attackers would break it, since you would apply it only to logout url, I don't really see what they can do. Maliciously logout the user? :-)

Comment: I agree, not many would be interested in maliciously logouting users :) Thanks for your replays though, might be I'll find some time to figure out how to disable csrf for cas server only, but disabling it for logout url seems good enouth.